# IP addresses not found in routing table

Tags: networking, routes, ip-address

I have to questions about routing packets:

1. If a router receives a packet that is not listed in its routing table,      what are the possible actions it will do ?
2. What will be the network address and sub-net mask to configure a default route on a router ?

What would be the answers ?
I feel that both question are related.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, a router will not have the exact destination IP address of a packet in its routing table so it will look for a match for a route.  The longest match wins, and a packet will be forwarded to the interface with the longest match.  If no match is found, the router has no place to forward the packet, and the packet will be dropped.

For IPv4, a default route would be `0.0.0.0` with a mask of `0.0.0.0`; for IPv6, a default route would be `::/0`.  A default route would be the shortest match so it would be the last choice for packet forwarding.

Comment: so both questions are related ?? 
if there is no suitable path to send the packet to, the router just sends it to the default router address assigned to it ?? 
I found that sometimes the default router mask might be one of the interfaces that are connected to that router, is this right??

Comment: The router may or may not have a default route configured. If not, a packet with no route will be dropped. I don't understand your question about the default router mask. The mask for a default route (different than a default router) is 0.0.0.0 for IPv4. Are you asking about the actions of a router, or the actions of a client device? Your comment is very confusing.

Comment: I was confused with what I found in this link :
http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/79/configure-a-default-route-on-a-cisco-router/

can you explain the two shaded lines in blue please

Comment: These commands will set default routes in a router which tell the router where to forward a packet if there is no route in the routing table that matches the destination IP address. The first method will forward the packet to a specific address which may be accesses through one or more router interfaces. The second command will forward the packet to a specific interface. The key is that a default route will not be used if a longer match exists in the routing table.